# How to use the return-value of type js.Dynamic properly in scala-js?

Tags: firebase, scala.js

I'm trying to use firebase from within a scala-js app.
I'm struggling with the conversion of the firebase-result to scala.

I used the firebase.d.ts file of the definitely typed repo to create the scala-classes. With some tweaks it works fine so far.

I used this example-code to get some data out of the firebase sample-repository:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://gjauaudjwdc.firebaseio-demo.com/');

        myDataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
            console.log("   received value: ", snapshot.val());
            console.log("toString'ed value: ", snapshot.val().toString());
        });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The log properly writes down the received snapshot (a json-object).

```
   received value:  Object {-ImBnHMmOnndxre8XSkl: Object, -ImBnI0WLch7L7ndl6Qd: Object}
toString'ed value:  [object Object]
```

Here is the scala-js-version

```scala
package example

import de.flwi.firebase._

import scala.scalajs.js

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {

  def main(): Unit = {

    val rootRef: Firebase = FirebaseFactory.create("https://gjauaudjwdc.firebaseio-demo.com/")

    rootRef.on1("value", callback = { (snapshot: FirebaseDataSnapshot) => {
        println(snapshot.value())
      } 
    })    
  }    
}
```

When I try the same with my Firebase-wrapper from scala-js, I only get a `[object Object]` written down to the console. Like in the first example when calling toString() on the received value.

The corresponding traits looks like this (shortened):

```scala
trait FirebaseDataSnapshot extends js.Object {
  @JSName("val") def value(): js.Dynamic = js.native
}

trait FirebaseQuery extends js.Object {
  @JSName("on") def on1(eventType: String, callback: js.Function1[FirebaseDataSnapshot, Unit], cancelCallback: js.Function1[js.Any, Unit] = ???, context: Object = ???): js.Function1[FirebaseDataSnapshot, Unit] = js.native
  @JSName("on") def on2(eventType: String, callback: js.Function2[FirebaseDataSnapshot, String, Unit], cancelCallback: js.Function1[js.Any, Unit] = ???, context: Object = ???): js.Function2[FirebaseDataSnapshot, String, Unit] = js.native

}

@JSName("Firebase")
trait Firebase extends FirebaseQuery {

}

import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.{global => g, newInstance => jsnew}

@JSName("Firebase")
object FirebaseFactory {
  def create(url: String): Firebase = jsnew(g.Firebase)(url).asInstanceOf[Firebase]

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to deal with the js.Dynamic in the right way, like iterating over the values of the jsObject?

I uploaded the [project to github](https://github.com/FloWi/firebaseFirstSteps) with both examples (index-with-js.html and index.fastopt.html)

Comment: A minor comment: I'd suggest overloading the `on` methods, rather than adding the "1"/"2".

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend interpreting the object as a `js.Dictionary`:

```
trait FirebaseDataSnapshot extends js.Object {
  @JSName("val") def value(): js.Dictionary[js.Any] = js.native
}
```

`js.Dictionary` has all the methods of a `scala.Map` (added implicitly). So you can now simply write a for loop (or call `get`):

```
rootRef.on1("value", callback = { (snapshot: FirebaseDataSnapshot) => {
    // iterate over key value pairs
    for ((key, value) <- snapshot) println(key)

    // get a particular key
    snapshot.get("foo") // returns an Option
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@gzmo's answer is correct in the general case. But if you know what the structure of the returned object is going to be (I don't know Firebase, but that's often true of database calls -- you know exactly what fields should be defined in the result), you could define a facade trait for the result and cast snapshot to that using asInstanceOf[].  I'd probably recommend that as a more strongly-typed approach, *if* the resulting fields are reasonably consistent: facades are typically easier to work with in Scala code.

These answers aren't either/or -- for instance, you could treat it as a Dictionary for logging purposes, then cast it to the facade before handing it off to higher-level code.